# Getting type arguments cannot be inferred error from function that accepts 2 type args

Tags: c#, exception

Okay, I need to be able to pass in an anonymous method and an exception type to check against. Here's a stripped out version of what I'm trying now

```
public T MyMethod<T,E>(Func<T> action, E ExceptionType, int param2, int param3 = 3) where E : Exception
{
    try
    {
    //Some code here
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        if(ex.GetType() == typeof(ExceptionType))
        {
         //Do something
        }
        else
        {
          //Do something else
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to call the method like this

```
Retry(()=>OtherMethod("input"),typeof(Exception),33,9);
```

And I keep getting the same error. 
"The type arguments for method X cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly"

The idea is to check to see if an exception thrown inside MyMethod matches the type of exception that was passed in as the second argument, and take an action based on whether it does or not. I can't just hard code the type because this is to be used in a library and the type of exception to check for will not always be the same.

What can I change to accomplish what I am trying?

EDIT:
I've also tried to call the method like so..

```
Retry(()=OtherMethod(),new Exception(),10,10)
```

But I get the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Servy's answer is correct. Some thoughts on how to fix your problem:

First option: take a type:

```
public T MyMethod<T>(Func<T> action, Type exceptionType)
{
    ...
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        if(ex.GetType() == exceptionType)
```

Second option: take a type parameter:

```
public T MyMethod<T, E>(Func<T> action)
  where E : Exception 
{
    ...
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        if(ex.GetType() == typeof(E))
```

This solution has a problem: there is no basis upon which to infer the type parameter E, so the caller cannot use type inference.

A third option:

```
public T MyMethod<T>(Func<T> action, Exception example)
{
    ...
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        if(ex.GetType() == example.GetType())
```

Yuck. Passing in an object just so that you can extract its type is weird.

All solutions have a problem with the comparison:

```
if(ex.GetType() == exceptionType)
if(ex.GetType() == typeof(E))
if(ex.GetType() == example.GetType())
```

This is problematic; suppose the exception type is AnimalException and ex is of type GiraffeException, which derives from AnimalException. These tests will fail, since the types are not *equal*, and that's an *equality* check. If you go with this approach, consider whether an exact match of types is what you really want.

> I was hoping to be able to pass in a Type but have it restricted to only types that inherit from Exception

Oh, well, why didn't you say so?

```
public T MyMethod<T>(Func<T> action, Type exceptionType)
{
    if (!typeof(Exception).IsAssignableFrom(exceptionType))
        throw new ArgumentException("exceptionType must represent a type derived from or equal to Exception");
```

Easy peasy. Don't try to capture everything in the type system. Your callers who violate this rule will discover it quickly and fix the problem.

Comment: You have a great point. I need to rethink this.

If this case I think an exact match to exception type or any derived type is what I need. Essentially the caller needs to pass in an exception type that is "acceptable" and my method needs to tell something else to run if that exception type is encountered. To expand on your example, if E is AnimalException, any exception derived from Animal Exception should be considered "acceptable", but this breaks down if the caller passes in `Exception` as E, as then any exception type would be considered ok, wouldn't it?

Comment: Hmm...Still having issue. I have changed my method definition to something like this `public T MyMethod<T>(Func<T> action, Type ExceptionType, int param2, int param3 = 3)` and tried calling it with `MyMethod((()=>OtherMethod(),typeof(NotImplementedException),4,4)` and get the same error.

Comment: @Rocky: Well then let's try out my psychic powers this morning. Is `OtherMethod()` void-returning perchance? Inference will fail if T is inferred to be void. You can't have a void-returning `Func<T>`; that's `Action`.

Comment: It is for my testing, but it probably won't always be in production. Why?

Comment: Well it better not be in production, since your program won't compile. If you intend that thing to be an action, pass `Action`.

Comment: Ah....whoops. Well there you go then. Is there some way to allow for possible void returning methods to be called?

Comment: Nope. Make two versions, one that takes `Func<T>` and one that takes `Action`. This is what you get for using a type system that does not treat `void` as a unit type.

Comment: I made a copy and made that switch, everything is working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `typeof(Exception)` evaluates to `Type`.  `Type` doesn't meet the criteria for the type that it needs to extend `Exception`.

The method is expecting you to pass an instance of some kind of exception, not a `Type` object that is an exception.

If you want to pass the type itself, don't try to infer the generic arguments - explicitly specify the exception as the generic type argument.  If you want to pass a `Type`, write the method to accept one.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to pass in a `Type` but have it restricted to only types that inherit from `Exception`. I've also tried calling the method with `Retry(()=>OtherMethod(),new Exception(),4,4)` but it also fails with the same error.